# Skrill redirect error "JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment, skrill

I'm using Skrill payment method in my asp.net web application.

When clicked on booking button it redirects to the Skrill for payments as:

```
protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Mastercard   5438311234567890
    // Visa         4000001234567890
    // Amex         371234500012340

    string url = "https://pay.skrill.com/?";

    // Merchant Details
    url += "pay_to_email=" + "demoqco@sun-fish.com";
    url += "&recipient_description=" + "Banquet Halls Booking System";
    url += "&language=" + "EN";
    url += "&status_url=" + "";

    // Customer Details
    url += "&country=" + "Pakistan";

    // Payment Details
    url += "&amount=" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", (double.Parse(lblGrandTotal.Text) / 110.00));
    url += "&currency=" + "USD";
    url += "&amount2_description=" + Persons.Text + ":";
    url += "&amount2=" + lblPersons.Text;
    url += "&amount3_description=" + PerHeadRate.Text + ":";
    url += "&amount3=" + lblPerHeadRate.Text;
    url += "&amount4_description=" + Tax.Text + ":";
    url += "&amount4=" + lblTax.Text + "%";
    url += "&detail1_description=" + "Booking ID:";
    url += "&detail1_text=" + objDLBkg.SelectLastBkID();
    url += "&detail2_description=" + "Description:";
    url += "&detail2_text=" + "View all bookings in your Account.";
    url += "&detail3_description=" + "Banquet Hall:";
    url += "&detail3_text=" + lblBqtName.Text;
    url += "&detail4_description=" + "Booking Date:";
    url += "&detail4_text=" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

    // Split Gateway
    url += "&payment_methods=" + "WLT,ACC";

    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

And shows error on redirect to Skrill:

> JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 -
>
> ---
>
> JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report
> JBWEB000068: message
> JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
>
> ---
>
> JBoss Web/7.5.9.Final-redhat-1

How I can solve it? Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Not every character is valid in literal form in query string, some need to be escaped, and you don't do any escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that there is a special character `%` used in my redirect server-URL that's caused the error here:

```
url += "&amount4=" + lblTax.Text + "%";
```

Just removed `%` character from URL and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your querystring parameters to escape special characters, an example of how to do that are available in answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885353/uri-escapeuristring-how-do-i-use-it) :

```
string url = string.Format("https://yourdomain.com/api/add?t={0}&mac={1}&portName={2}&name={3}&location={4}&description={5}&comment={6}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(appToken),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(macAddress),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PortName),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Location),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(description),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Comment));
```

And similar error is reported here: [JBWEB000069](https://github.com/lightblue-platform/lightblue-rest/issues/38)